# How to save a pdf in selenium webdriver which opens in a separate window?

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver, save

```
<input type="button" name="common.image.alt.print" value="Print   
  onclick="window.open('/ftol/pdf/RenderForm.do?   
formId=23907&formType=DEP_RECEIPT_RSP');clickPrint(0)" class="btnFont floatLeft" id="btn_0" alt="Print" />
```

Comment: Does it have to open in a separate window first? There are a number of options depending on the browser to specify that PDFs automatically save bypassing showing up in a separate window.

Comment: Yes it has to open in a separate window as per requirements.

Comment: The application works only in IE so are there any preferences to be set in IE?